How do I get enclosure glass for this tub?
We are remodeling our bathroom. The contractor and plumber made a plan that adds this strange elevated ledge to the drain side of the tub. Now no standard tub glass works. Any ideas what we can do?


This is what my wife wanted:

Thanks for your help.

So why was the ledge needed?   Is the glass in the pic of what your wife wants available in kit form?  Do you realize the glass that wife wants is set up for a tub/ shower with a different design?

visit a glass shop

Why don't you download all these pictures and edit them into your question.

Why can't the glass sit on top of the ledge?

@SiHa I suspect the OP wants to have glass on the tub short side and on the long side.  The knee wall makes it impossible to use an OTS glass because the long side glass must now be cut to fit the wall profile.  Although the "what my wife wanted" pic could still easily be done, since it has a gap in the glass.

Pethaps you should have communicated what you wanted, with the contractor before they finished. You have a custom install of the tub, so you need a custom glass solution.
Either ask the contractor to remove the ledge or ask a glass company to give you a custom solution.

Yes, OP should have shared the "what my wife wanted" pic with the contractor.  If he failed to do so, that's kinda on him.

I did share it, and this is what he did. Thanks for your positivity.
